# Is there a way to check for dropped messages that don't have headers?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In particular, I am sending some `joy/Joy` messages over a WLAN and am hinting `ros::TransportHints().unreliable()` in the subscriber (the publisher is a `joy/joy_node`).

I've occasionally seen a delay of > 0.5 s, where the in the received messages based on timing within the subscriber's callback, and I'd like to see if that might have to do with dropped UDP packets. I was thinking that I would just look at the `header.seq` field in each received message, looking for and increment greater than 1, and then realized that `joy/Joy` messages have no header.

Am I SOL or is there some way to determine whether messages are being dropped?

I also wonder about out-of-order messages which I think are theoretically possible with UDP and was hoping to also watch out for those in a similar manner. Maybe a `Header` could be added to `joy/Joy` in a future release?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9503/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-dropped-messages-that-don%27t-have-headers?/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding a Header seems like the best solution to me.

For backwards compatibility, maybe create a JoyStamped message.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-05-04**:
I'm planning on putting a timestamp on a the Joy msg in the next release. These is a ticket here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/3998

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-03-20**:
Would backwards compatibility really be an issue, though? Usually you wouldn't have one part of a system running say, C-Turtle, and the other Diamondback. Creating a new message type would mean that all publishers and subscribers would have to be recoded. Just changing the message, they wouldn't.